# Linux (Ubuntu) CIFS mount with restrictive umask

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, mount, cifs

I'm trying to mount a NAS share using CIFS in Ubuntu 14.04. This is my personal share and I'd like to make sure that files are readable only by me and not by anyone else logged in. So ideally, I'd like to use something like a `umask=...` in my `mount` command to make sure that files and directories always show up with their group and other permissions set to 0.

Unfortunately, `umask` parameter is not supported by `mount.cifs`. The command offers two other arguments (`file_mode` and `dir_mode`) but those seem to only have effect on newly created files, as no matter what values I specify, the files and directories on my mounted share always show up with mode 0777.

Is there any trick to force specific permission on mounted files and directories (short of making the parent of mount directory mode `0700`)?

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to mount the cifs share into a personal folder as ubuntu does for example. Set your rights for /media/user and then mount it on /media/user/share.

The other (and nicer) possibility is to use pam_mount. It's a user-based mount system which means the mounts don't appear in the fstab. Every user can set its own mounts. I really like this system. Then, in your personal (or global) configuration file, set the mount option dir_mode=0700 for your volume. It works fine for me, just tried it. Be sure to allow user-mounts and the dir_mode option in the global configuration file.

Good luck!

Comment: Just to make things easier for your: if you use the second option (what i would appreciate) here is a sample volume entry in my ~/.pam_mount.conf.xml:
<volume fstype="cifs" server="192.168.0.110" path="Multimedia" mountpoint="~/media/Multimedia" options="nosuid,nodev,dir_mode=0700,cred=/home/%(USER)/.mynas.cred" />

Answer (score 0):

If you add cifsacl as an option to the cifs command (it must be defined earlier in the same file, pam_mount.conf.xml) you needn't specify dir_mode or file_mode: the mount will use 0700 as mask and will honour the remote  ACLs of files and directories.